# AttributeError: type object 'Fernet' has no attribute 'generar_key'

Tags: python, encriptación, datos

pido anticipadamente disculpas por si mi error es muy de novato, pero intento encontrar porque no está bien la línea 8 (`key = Fernet.generar_key()`) y no estaría consiguiéndolo. Les dejo mi código:

```
from importlib.resources import path
from queue import Full
from sys import path_importer_cache
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os

def generar_key():
    key = Fernet.generar_key()
    with open ('key.key', 'wb') as filekey:
        filekey.write(key)

def cargar_key():
    return open ('key.key', 'rb').read()

def encrypt(items, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    for item in items:
        with open(item, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
        with open(item, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path_to_encrypt = 'C:\\Users\\U***l\\Desktop\\M****a'
    items = os.listdir(path_to_encrypt)
    full_path = [path_to_encrypt+'\\'+item for item in items]

    generar_key()
    key = cargar_key()

    encrypt(full_path, key)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Puede ser que te hayas querido referir a Fernet.generate_key en lugar de Fernet,generar_key?

Comment: Dudo que ese módulo criptográfico tenga un método en español. Según [la documentación](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/), en la declaración de `key`, en la primera función, debe ser: `key = Fernet.generate_key()`

Comment: Gracias a ambos! Ya corregí eso en mi código y ahora funciona correctamente

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.